# JavaScript localeCompare don't sort well [ "aaa-1.0", "aaa-1.1", "aaa-1.01", "aaa-11","aaa-2.01"]

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'd like to sort strings by their "decimal" number value as well as alphabetically. Keeping the natural order of it.

```
var strArray = ["aaa-0", "aaa-0.01", "aaa-1.0", "aaa-1.1", "aaa-1.01", "aaa-2.01", "bbb-2.01", "aaa-11", "aaa-2.01"]

strArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b,undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
});
```

Returns :

```
["aaa-0", "aaa-0.01", "aaa-1.0", "aaa-1.1", "aaa-1.01", "aaa-2.01", "aaa-2.01", "aaa-11", "bbb-2.01"]
```

While i'd like to have:

```
["aaa-0", "aaa-0.01", "aaa-1.0", "aaa-1.01", "aaa-1.1", "aaa-2.01", "aaa-2.01", "aaa-11", "bbb-2.01"]
```

How this can be acomplished? Even if I use "," instead of "." the sorting is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort the numerics and alphabets separately.

**DEMO**

```js
var strArray = ["aaa-0", "aaa-0.01", "aaa-1.0", "aaa-1.1", "aaa-1.01", "aaa-2.01", "bbb-2.01", "aaa-11", "aaa-2.01"]

strArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  var splitA = a.split("-");
  var splitB = b.split("-");
  if (splitA[0] == splitB[0]) {
    return (Number(splitA[1]) - Number(splitB[1]));
  } else {
    return splitA[0].localeCompare(splitB[0], undefined, {
      numeric: true,
      sensitivity: 'base'
    });
  }
});
console.log(strArray);
```

Comment: it works in my case, unfortunately it's not a general purpose solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could set the flag `ignorePunctuation` in the [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters) to `true`.

```js
var array = ["aaa-0", "aaa-0.01", "aaa-1.0", "aaa-1.1", "aaa-1.01", "aaa-2.01", "bbb-2.01", "aaa-11", "aaa-2.01"]

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { ignorePunctuation: true, numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base' });
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @GabrielBleu, not on edge.

Comment: @GabrielBleu, it looks like it is dependent on the user agent implementation.